# Page doesnot scroll when nesting ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a ListView(2) nested inside another ListView(1).

Whenever I replace 2 with a container, the whole page scrolls fine but as soon as I enable both list views inside each other, both stop scrolling.

This is the main ListView implementation

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: ListView(
        primary: true, //does not have any effect
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Container( ...etc.
```

And this is the second listview implementation inside the first listview:

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
      primary: false,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expanded` cannot be used in a `ListView`

Try this using `SizedBox` and setting the height to a desire number

If you want the ListView(2) to take the entire screen (and more) try this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.pink,
            width: 400,
            height: 800
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: ListView(
              children: List.generate(300, (i) => Text(i.toString()))
            ),
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked Perfectly. Expanded was the problem.

Comment: Hey @Josteve how do I make it so that the SizedBox takes as much height as required by the ListView? I am fetching 100 posts from db and users can scroll till the very end. I can't provide that in an static way.

Comment: Actually nesting listView inside another is not a good design. Use Slivers instead